# Universal USB Installer for Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb

Is there any tool in Ubuntu to create a bootable USB stick of an OS other than Ubuntu? Like Universal USB Installer in Windows.

Comment: Related: [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Startup Disk Creator seems to support any Debian-based distro, including Debian and Mint.

Answer (score 1):

**mkusb** is a tool that can work in several linux distros and that can create USB drives of several linux distros as well as Windows install drives.

You install it into Ubuntu and Ubuntu community flavours via a PPA with the following command lines.

If you run standard Ubuntu *live*, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb usb-pack-efi
```

Read more at the following link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Answer (score 1):

**UNetbootin**

If you don't need anything fancy, persistence limited to 4GB, Works with many distro's.

https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html

Otherwise **mkusb**

Answer (score 0):

Try using LiLi USB Creator. You can download it from https://www.linuxliveusb.com/